# How to capture the User ID using magento's customer Token?

Tags: magento2, customer, api, rest-api

How do I make a call to that URL that captures the  User ID, using Magento **customer Token** in magento 2 rest API?

How Magento 2 makes calls in-between for the APIs ?

Comment: you can directly pass      <parameter name="customer.id" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>

Comment: it worked!! gives me customer id based on token. Thanks!

Comment: You can mark as right if it's working fine for you, it may help future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **How magento 2 make calls in-between for the APIs ?**

Magento gets the customer data with passing anything except **token value** in **API** call.

In between magento calls some API related controllers for the same

> vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/customers/me" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface" method="getById"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
        </data>
 </route>
```

**in this API call magento get customer data based on token.**

Based on API url `url="/V1/customers/me"` magento calls function from

Magento calls In-between call of dispatch function.

> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php

```
 public function dispatch(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
 {
     /** In between code **/
     // In the same file
     $this->processApiRequest();

 }
 protected function processApiRequest()
 {
      $inputParams = $this->getInputParamsResolver()->resolve();
 }
```

**And this `resolve()` function calls `override()` function**

> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php

```
 public function resolve()
 {
      $inputData = $this->paramsOverrider->override($inputData, $route->getParameters());
 }
```

and `overide()` function calls `getOverriddenValue()` function

> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/ParamsOverrider.php

```
 public function override(array $inputData, array $parameters)
 {
      $value = $this->paramOverriders[$paramValue]->getOverriddenValue();
 }
```

`getOverriddenValue()` calls `ParamOverriderInterface`

> vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/Rest/Request/ParamOverriderInterface.php

- To Override parameter values
- Parameters in the webapi.xml can be forced. This ensures that on
  specific routes, a specific value is always used.
- For instance, if there is a `".../me/..."` route, the route should use
  only user information specific to the
- currently logged in user. More specifically, if there was a
  `"/customers/me/addresses"` route, the service method
- invoked could have a signature of `"getAddresses($customerId)"`, but in
  the `webapi.xml`, the $customerId parameter
- **would be forced to be the customer id of the current authenticated
  user.**
- **The forced override parameter configuration is in the webapi.**

---

```
   <data>
     <parameter name="customer.id" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
   </data>
```

and for business logic of this function is in file -

> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/ParamOverriderCustomerId.php

```
   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public function getOverriddenValue()
   {
       if ($this->userContext->getUserType() === UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER) {
           return $this->userContext->getUserId();
   }
   return null;
   }
```

**So this is how Magento get Customer Id between API calls !!**

---

**Another solution**

```
$ch = curl_init('dev.magento2.com/rest/V1/customers/me');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);
echo $json->id;
```